# create-react-app no longer watches changes to files

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

After upgrading to the newest version of create-react-app I've run into a bit of a big problem where web pack no longer watches for changes.

In my project I use `node_modules` to keep all of my project source code, and while I can import code from here without problems, web pack no longer watches this folder which means any changes made require restarting the project which is very frustrating.

bellow is an example of what my project structure looks like:

```
my-app/
  node_modules/
  package.json
  .gitignore
  public/
    favicon.ico
    index.html
  src/
    node_modules/
        my_app/
            components/
                ui/
            resources/
                styles/
                images/
    App.js
    index.js
```

Again, creating an consuming a new component is no problem, but making changes no longer get updated live in the browser, and I can't seem to find what the solution is.

Comment: Could you tell us why you're putting everything in `node_modules` directory?

Comment: why two folders of `node_modules`

Comment: to clarify, I'm not putting why source in the root `node_modules` folder, but rather a `node_modules` folder I've created in `src`. To truly fix the problem I was having I needed to modify the webpackDevServer.config.js as you mentioned to `watchOptions: {
      ignored: 'node_modules/**',
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react-scripts` in `create-react-app`, there is a configuration for webpackDevServer; [webpackDevServer.config.js](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/eadfad28f448fffd581c36b8769b32b51474962b/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js#L78)

There the directory `node_modules` is ignored. Could you remove this and try out?

Comment: I commented out that line. And logged some dummy string in one of the packages I am using. It's not showing anything in the console log. And I have just one `node_module` in the root and `src` as well. Can you help me to watch node_module files?